# Salvar checkbox no mysql com php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, checkbox

To tentando salvar esse formulário no banco de dados mas quando cheguei na parte dos checkbox não consegui salvar no banco. Segue os códigos que tentei usar.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<label><b>Como você ficou sabendo do empreendimento? <span>*</span> </b></label>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Site" name="sabendo[]">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Site</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Facebook" name="sabendo[]">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Fecebook</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Google" name="sabendo[]">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Google</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Jornal" name="sabendo[]">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Jornal</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Panfletos" name="sabendo[]">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Panfleto</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Imobiliaria" name="sabendo[]">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Imobiliária</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="Outros" name="sabendo[]">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">Outros</label>
</div>
```

PHP Salvando no banco:

```
if(isset($_POST['sabendo'])){
$listaCheckbox = $_POST['sabendo'];
foreach ($listaCheckbox as $sabendo) {
    echo $sabendo;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO form_cidades (nome, email, tempo, cordialidade, info, comentario, sabendo, imobi) VALUES('$nome', '$email', '$tempo', '$cordialidade', '$info', '$comentario', '$sabendo', '$imobi')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
}
```

}

Comment: algum erro? chega a montar corretamente a query? alguma pista??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oi @MBoss,

Tira o foreach, e usa um implode, ficaria assim:

```
$sabendo = $_POST['sabendo'];
$sabendo_implode = implode(",",$sabendo);

$sql = "INSERT INTO form_cidades (nome, email, tempo, cordialidade, info, comentario, sabendo, imobi) VALUES('$nome', '$email', '$tempo', '$cordialidade', '$info', '$comentario', '$sabendo_implode ', '$imobi')";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
```

Desse modo, vc vai salvar todos os valores dos checkboxes marcados, separados por vírgula dentro do campo "sabendo". Quando vc quiser fazer a leitura deles via select faz o explode assim:

```
$sabendo = $row['sabendo'];
$sabendo_explode = explode(",",$sabendo);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo, resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Feliz em ter ajudado, bom trabalho.

Comment: Fantástico, me ajudou a eliminar passos desnecessários, muito obrigado pela contribuição.